# How to display data from firebase in vis.js timeline

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vis.js

I m using vis.js timeline and i want display date from firestore. It works when I type manually (look --> **this.items**), but does not work with firestore (look --> **this.users**).
I m using Vue framework.

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
      items: [
        {
          id: '1',
          content: 'London',
          group: 'Mike',
          start: '2021-12-20',
          end: '2022-06-19',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    await this.loadPlaces()
  },
  methods: {
    async loadPlaces() {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'places'))

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        this.users.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
      })

      this.$store.commit('places/setPlaces', this.users)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    places() {
      return this.$store.state.places.places
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    let container = document.getElementById('visualization')

    let options = {
      moveable: true,
    }

    let timeline = new vis.Timeline(container)
    timeline.setOptions(options)
    timeline.setGroups(this.groups)
    timeline.setItems(this.items)
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I just moved all code from `mounted()` to method `loadPlaces` (under `this.$store.commit`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself trouble and use the vis datasets instead.

my pinia store in vue 3 looks like this.

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { DataSet } from 'vis-data/esnext'


export const useVisData = defineStore('visData', {
    state: () => ({
        items: new DataSet([]),
        groups: new DataSet([]),
        selectedItems: [],
        serializedGroupsAndItems: []

    }),
    actions: {

        //Group actions

        showAllGroups() {
            this.groups.forEach(group => {
                this.groups.updateOnly({ id: group.id, visible: true })
            });
        },
        addGroup(group) {
            this.groups.add(group)
        },
        hideGroup(group) {
            this.groups.updateOnly({ id: group, visible: false })
        },

        //Item actions

        addItem(item) {
            this.items.add(item)
        },
        removeItem(item) {
            this.items.remove(item)
        },
        setSelectedItems(items) {
            this.selectedItems = items
        },

        //data add/remove

        serializeData() {
            this.serializedGroupsAndItems.push({
                groups: JSON.stringify(this.groups.get()),
                items: JSON.stringify(this.items.get())
            })
        },
        loadSerializedData() {
            this.clearGroupsAndItems()
            
            this.serializedGroupsAndItems.forEach(data => {
                this.addGroup(JSON.parse([data.groups]))
                this.addItem(JSON.parse([data.items]))
            })
        },

        //misc

        clearGroupsAndItems() {
            this.groups.clear()
            this.items.clear()
        }

    },
    getters: {
        getHiddenGroups(state) {
            return state.groups.get({
                filter: (item) => {
                    return item.visible === false
                }
            })
        }
    }

})
```

Also remember to watch for changes in your options.

Might be better to wrap it in a vue component too. something like this.
this is what i did.

```js
let timeline;
const visref = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => {
    timeline = new Timeline(visref.value, props.items, props.groups, {...props.options, ...timelineOptions});

    props.events.forEach(event => {
        on(event, (properties) => {
            // console.log(event, properties)
            emits(`vis${event}`, properties);
        });
    });

})

<template>
    <div ref="visref"></div>
</template>
```

then you can use it like so:

```js
const timelineref = ref();

      <Timeline
        ref="timelineref"
        :items="visStore.items"
        :groups="visStore.groups"
        :options="options"
      />
```

remember to expose the instance in your timeline component then you can call the functions using a ref like this.

```js
timelineref.value.timeline.zoomOut(0.5)
```